# ESXI cannot boot with external hdd

Tags: vmware-esxi, boot, hard-drive

I've tried to make ESXI vm's to boot up automatically when a reset happened to ESXI host(HP dl380), and I've got an external H.D.D connected to it for backup purpose

but the problem is that ESXI would not boot when the power goes and get back!

it will stuck on booting up from drive c:

anyone knows what is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESXi is based on linux, so if you are getting a problem booting drive C: then it is indicative of a much larger problem.

Check your BIOS to ensure you are not set to boot off any external drives, or anything but the primary controller for that matter. If you are still experiencing issues, you might want to include your disk configuration and any errors it is giving you.

I am assuming the server will boot without the external drive attached, since you went out of your way to mention it.